# how to cbind many data-frames?

Tags: r, loops, cbind

I have 247 data frames which are sequentially named (y1, y2, y3, ...., y247). They are resulted from the following code:

```
for (i in (1:247)) {

  nam <- paste("y", i, sep = "")
  assign(nam, dairy[dairy$FARM==i,"YIT"])
}
```

I wish to cbind all of them to have:

```
df <- cbind(y1,y2,...,y247)
```

Can I do this with a loop without typing all 247 data frames?

Thanks

Comment: You might be able to store the data sets in a list `X <- split(dairy$YIT, dairy$FARM)` and then bind via `do.call(cbind, X)`.

Comment: Why are you doing this? It looks like you already have all the data in a single data frame? Is `dairy[dairy$FARM %in% 1:247, "YIT"]` what you are looking for?

Comment: I interpreted this as something like `spread` from tidyverse, i.e. wanting to each column to represent the YIT data for a specific value of a key (the FARM variable).

Comment: You may find these threads useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60321045/cbind-with-loop-in-r and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46058850/r-cbind-function-in-for-loop. Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48233811/r-cbinding-lists-of-data-tables which uses mapply instead of a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this, it is possible:

```r
df <- y1
for (i in 2:247) {
  df <- cbind(df, eval(parse(text=paste("y", i, sep = ''))))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating many variables in a loop as you do is not a good idea. You should use a list instead:

```
ys <- split(dairy$FARM, dairy$FARM)
names(ys) <- paste0("y", names(ys))
```

The first line creates list `ys` that contains your `y1` as its first element (`ys[[1]]`), your `y2` as its second element (`ys[[2]]`) and so on. The second line names the list elements the same way as you named your variables (`y1`, `y2`, etc.), since those will in the end
be used to name the columns in the data frame.

There is a function in the `dplyr` package that takes a list of data frames and binds them all together as columns:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- bind_cols(ys)
```

Note, by the way, that this will only work, if each value appears exactly the same number of times in the column `FARM`, since the columns in a data frame must all have the same length.